# Sporadic exceptions calling a web service that is load balanced

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service that I am running on three load balanced web servers and I am getting sporadic errors. Now, I admit that the load balanced part may be a bit of a red herring, but when I test with only 1 web server I cannot reproduce the error. If I test with all three web servers I can get the error (but it is not 100% of the time, more like 50%). All testing is done through the load balancer, we just tell the load balancer how many servers we want to farm.

The code is simple single request code. That is, there is no state. A request is made and a response is returned. The web service code is c# .NET 4 running on IIS 7.5. The client code is both a web site and a desktop app.

I get one of two exceptions:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   An unsecured or incorrectly secured
>   fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException
>   for the fault code and detail. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   The security context token is expired
>   or is not valid. The message was not
>   processed.

Or I get:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
>   Secure channel cannot be opened
>   because security negotiation with the
>   remote endpoint has failed. This may
>   be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the
>   EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the
>   EndpointIdentity specified or implied
>   by the EndpointAddress correctly
>   identifies the remote endpoint.  --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   The request for security token has
>   invalid or malformed elements.

As you can see from the following snips from my .config files, I am not using security as this is strictly an internal web service. (names have been changed to protect the innocent--namely me).

Server Side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<!-- Service Side web.config -->
...
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="InternalUseOnly.InternalUseOnlyServiceBehavior" name="InternalUseOnly.InternalUseOnlyService">
        <endpoint address="" bindingNamespace="http://somecompany.com/webservices" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="InternalUseOnly.IInternalUseOnlyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="InternalUseOnly.InternalUseOnlyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
...
</configuration>
```

Client side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Client Side web.config -->
<configuration>
...
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IInternalUseOnlyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
            <security mode="Message">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="http://intranet.somecompany.com/InternalUseOnly/InternalUseOnlyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IInternalUseOnlyService" contract="InternalUseOnlyService.IInternalUseOnlyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IInternalUseOnlyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
...
</configuration>
```

Thoughts anyone?

---

Additional information: After reviewing the answers below I have tried two things, both without success.

The most obvious change (which I did not notice at first) was to change one of properties on the client to allow cookies `<system.serviceModel><bindings><wsHttpBinding><binding name="blah, blah, blah" ... other properties... allowCookies="true" />` It defaults to false. Further, our load balancer uses cookies to keep affinity. But, it did not make a difference (no clue why yet).

Next, I tried various security options in the client side app.config file. This included both `<security mode="None" />` and a more elaborate:

```
<security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
    <message clientCredentialType="None" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false"/>
</security>
```

although the settings in the last one was just a guess on my part.  I did not make any server side changes to the app.config as I don't know what to change and, sadly, I can only test with production as we only have 1 dev web server, not three.

Comment: Using CRM2013 and the CrmConnection class from the Developer Extensions, we ran into the same problem today with a WCF Web Service that is not load-balanced. It was in the past, but we deactivated it to eliminate load-balancing as an error source. Before receiving these errors, I got lot's of connection aborts (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644847/frequent-connection-aborted-exceptions-when-using-crm-2013-organization-service). I am still not able to solve these issues, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelBarth Sorry, no I don't.

Comment: Too bad, but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: The culprit was load balancing after all. We didn't use load balancing for our WCF Service, but the CRM Organization Service was load balanced (which I did not know until know ^^). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26293822/85578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Chris and Jeff have help get me on the track to an answer, what actually solved it for me was this article i found from Microsoft on [Load Balancing Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx). In short, what we had to do to resolve this for our web farm was to switch from the default `wsHttpBinding` to `basicHttpBinding`. This was not difficult, but was an all-or-nothing move. The main web service and every client had to be reconfigured at the same time or it would break.

While `wsHttpBinding` does have a property of allowCooikes that could be set to true, it apparently does not use them until after the connection is made, at which point the request could jump servers on the first request and thus fail.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to go out on a limb here and guess that the security involved is the Message security specified on the client side:

```
<security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

If you are creating a client and connecting, the negotiated windows credential token may be cached.  If you don't have sticky sessions enabled, the token might be passed back to the wrong server and will fail.  My guess is that its always on the second call?

Comment: @Chris, are you saying that the above snip is *implied* or the default for security. I ask as I don't have that in my .config file (as seen above). Is there a way of turn security for this? This process is internal and even if it was hacked from the outside there is absolutely nothing that can be returned that isn't already publicly available elsewhere.  When you say "Sticky Sessions" are you referring to the load balancer. If so, yes, we have affinity on. And no, it is on the first call, if it fails.

Comment: Duh. When I did a search *before* my posting, I must have only searched the server side for "security". Sorry and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Chris. I am still having the same issues after trying a couple of things. I have added the details to the bottom of the main question due to length. If you can review it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: ok...  One more possibility.  This one is pretty out there but...  Check the system clocks on all of your servers, and make sure they are all in sync.

Comment: @Chris. Yes, that is pretty out there (as in I wouldn't have thought of that)... The clocks are in sync to at least one second. I did find an article that would let me examine cookies over at [megakemp.wordpress.com](http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/), but what I noticed is that I can't examine cookies until I send my first request, so if the `new Client()` code makes the first connection, I need the cookie from **that**. Or, I need to figure out how to disable security checks altogether.

Comment: Is the IIS site secured?  Meaning, does it allow anonymous access?  Try connecting with Firefox/Safari/Anything non-IE- can you connect without getting a login prompt?

Comment: Yes, anonymous access is allowed on the site. For example, I can go to  http://intranet.somecompany.com/InternalUseOnly/InternalUseOnlyService.svc and see the "You have created a service" screen.

Comment: Next item- try removing those endpoint identities.  I think that the second error, at least, may be stemming from having those in there.

Comment: I found this article from Microsoft on [Load Balancing Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx). Basically, it says I have two choices. Change from `WSHttp` to `Basic Http`, or, turn off Security Context Establishment for `WSHttp`. Either way, I need to make a breaking change to both the server and the clients.  We have decided to go with with `Basic Http`.  Thanks for pushing me in the right directions though.

Answer (score 2):

It is an NTLM problem caused by using load balancers without sticky sessions.  To correct the problem you need to configure session affinity (sticky session).  If you don't you will get a failure because part of the NTLM handshake happened on one server and the other part happens on another server.

Comment: Yes, our load balancer has session affinity on. So, unless creating the client side object (e.g. `client = new InternalUseOnlyServiceClient()`) is doing an initial handshake, then that shouldn't be a problem because it fails on the first call to the web service. If it **is** doing an initial handshake I then have to find out if the code generated by VS 2010 for the web service can be made to deal with cookies as that is how our balancer is configured.  Thoughts?

Comment: I am still having the same issues after trying a couple of things. I have added the details to the bottom of the main question due to length. If you can review it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Jim time to break out fiddler or a network sniffing tool to see exactly what is being sent from the client and received from the server.  If everything looks good on the client then time to go to the server.  Is it possible that the load balancer is tampering with the traffic which is causing WCF to throw a security fault?

Comment: @Jim Also, this MSDN article recommends turning off NTLM authentication with WCF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907174.aspx

Comment: basically it appears that what I am trying to do is not directly possible. I finally found an article that I mentioned as a comment on Chris' answer from Microsoft on [Load Balancing Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx). In short, it says I either have to switch to basic Http or turn off with Security Context Establishment WSHttp. Due to more pressing issues, it may be a day or two before I can get back to this. Our temp workaround is simply to have a single server farm to prevent the failure. Thanks for the help though.